# How to make bbmustache work with Elixir?

Tags: elixir, mustache

I'm trying to use the [bbmustache](https://hex.pm/packages/bbmustache) package with Elixir. Adapting the documentation from Erlang to Elixir I tried multiple calls but none seems to be working.

```
:bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", %{"name" => "hoge"})
# => "name: "

:bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", %{name: "hoge"})
# => "name: "

:bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", [{:name, "hoge"}])
# => "name: "

:bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", [{"name", "hoge"}])
# => "name: "
```

There is probably something I don't get yet about strings and binaries or something else.

If anyone knows how to make it work that'd be awesome :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Actually I managed to make it work by patching it and removing the `Key` conversion but it doesn't seem right :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bbmustache` seems to require the key of the Map or List of tuples to be char lists. This works:

```
iex(1)> :bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", %{'name' => "hoge"})
"name: hoge"
```

Also `render/3` you could pass the type of the keys.

```
iex(1)> :bbmustache.render("name: {{name}}", %{"name" => "hoge"}, [key_type: :binary])
"name: hoge"
```

Comment: Ok it _was_ an issue with strings! Thanks!